# Erro no Firefox: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: java, firefox, cors

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

No *Chrome* funciona normalmente.

Mesmo com a configuração *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* no CORS, o Firefox dá o erro:

> (traduzido) Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em http://localhost:8080/... (Motivo: símbolo 'access-control-allow-origin' faltando no cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' durante a pré-conexão CORS)
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/... (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Answer (score 4):

A aplicação que está servindo a URL acessada não mandou no header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` o valor: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

**O que isso significa?**

O header Access-Control-Allow-Origin bloqueia demais entradas no header da requisição que não estejam explicitados nele, ou seja, se um header não estiver ali listado não irá funcionar.

**Resolvendo seu problema**

Adicione `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

`response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin");`

**Documentação de ajuda**

Uma documentação bacana para este conteúdo é: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers

Comment: Fala aí, fera! Só faltou uma coisa: **explicar, de fato, como resolver o problema**. Se a intenção é só explicar a causa do erro e linkar a documentação (sem solucionar e/ou exemplificar), é melhor comentar a pergunta...

Comment: Eu não deixei explicitamente a resolução mas é bem simples, já editei adicionando a resolução do problema. Quanto a responder o que não depende de informação era implícito adicionar o header, por isso não falei expliquei o que estava causando.

Comment: Obrigado ferfabricio!! A sua dica resolveu o problema:
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin");

Comment: @ferfabricio agora sim! ;D

Answer (score -1):

O fato é que o Access-Control-Allow-Origin e Access-Control-Allow-Headers já estão setados no header, mas, aparentemente, o firefox não os identifica.
A mesma configuração funciona tranquilamente no Chrome...

Segue o setHeader completo:
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "*");

Depurando um pouco mais, percebi que o erro ocorre somente com o método  OPTIONS que antecede algumas vezes os método GET que leva um token consigo...

Answer (score -1):

Resolução:
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8081"); 
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "auth-token, access-control-allow-origin");

Dica: ferfabricio